# List<InterfaceImplementation> vs List<BaseClassExtension>

Tags: c#, .net

I have an interface (IFoo) and another interface (IBar) that contains a `List<IFoo>`  My goal is to implement IFoo (FooImp) and to use that in the implementation of IBar (BarImp). I understand that interfaces don't transfer attributes and that you should use abstract base classes but I cannot figure out how to make this work. Here are my interfaces and implementations that know would not work, but I used this as a starting point:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    bool BoolOne { get; set; }
}

public interface IBar
{
    List<IFoo> FooList { get; }
}

/// <summary> Implements IFoo interface </summary>
public class FooImp : IFoo
{
    public bool BoolOne { get; set; } //required interface implementation
    public bool BoolTwo { get; set; } //new property
}

/// <summary>Implements IBar interface </summary>
public class BarImp : IBar //Error - does not implement
{
    public List<FooImp> FooList { get; private set; } //Error: "Does not match the expected type 'IFoo'". No suprise here
}
```

Next, I converted the interfaces to abstract bases (FooBase & BarBase) and extended them (FooExt and BarExt):

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
    public abstract bool BoolOne { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BarBase
{
    public abstract List<FooBase> FooList { get; protected set; }
}

public class FooExt : FooBase
{
    public override bool BoolOne { get; set; } //implement abstract property

    public bool BoolTwo { get; set; } //add new property
}

 public class BarExt : BarBase //Error: FooList<FooBase> not implemented
{        
    public override List<FooExt> FooList { get; protected set; }      //Error: "Type must be FooBase"
}
```

I don't understand why there is an error on the last line, `"Type must be FooBase"`    . I thought FooExt is a FooBase by polymorphism.

I tried many, many (too many to list all here) combinations of Linq `ConvertAll()`, `overrride`, `new`, and passing values through constructors and other and could not find anything that would compile. Should I use a different design pattern?

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663677/changing-property-type-in-class-that-implements-interface-with-object-type-prope) because my list container is an interface. Those answers are helpful, but quite right for this question.

Comment: By overriding you cannot change the members signature.

Comment: Perhaps make `IBar` / `BarBase` a generic interface/class with a generic type parameter that specifies the element type for the `FooList` list (constraining this generic type parameter to types derived from `IFoo` / `FooBase` would be a good idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your overridden method you changed the type parameter. You cannot do that because it makes the signature different.

What you can do is to use generics:

```
public abstract class Base<T> where T : FooBase
{
    public abstract List<T> FooList { get; protected set; }
}
```

And then you can override this like that:

```
public class Ext : Base<FooExt>
{        
    public override List<FooExt> FooList { get; protected set; }
}
```

Comment: Whilst I explained the *why*, you explained the *how*. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

By overriding you cannot change the members signature.

Imagine a user of your program gets an instance of `BarBase`, e.g. from a sever or whatever.

```
class MyServer
{
    public BarBase GetBar() { ... }
}

var bar = server.GetBar();
```

How should that user know that this instances `FooList`-property actually contains instances of `FooExt`? It can´t, because the *contract* provided by `BarBase` just states `List<FooBase>`.

If we *were* able to do this, we could also add an instance of `AnotherFoo` into that list, that also inherits from `FooBase`:

```
bar.FooList.Add(new AnotherBar())
```

Now your `FooList` would contain both, `FooExt`- and `AnotherBar`-instances.

Thus when overriding you have to use the exact same signature as the overriden member.